# Change selectBox default language [select2]

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a selectbox which lists with ajax. I want to change the language. I found language plugins. How do I use this at http://www.tes-is.org.tr/assets/plugins/select2/i18n/tr.js?
Thanks in advance

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").attr("data-placeholder", "Lütfen Kurum Seçiniz..");
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    language: "tr",
    ajax: {
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `select2` default language like given below example.

```js
 $('.select2').select2({
language: "hi"
 });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/i18n/hi.js"></script>
<select class="select2">
<option>Search in hindi</option>
<option>एक</option>
<option>दो</option>
<option>तीन</option>
<option>चार</option>
<option>पंज</option>
<option>हम परीक्षण कर रहे हैं</option>
</select>
```

Comment: select2 I am using version 3.5.2. Version 3.5.2 worked by adding the language library. Than you